# How can ı download polybar for Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, updates, google-chrome, amavisd-new

I'm using "Ubuntu 20.04" I want to download "polybar". How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Polybar was added to the Ubuntu repositories *after* Ubuntu 20.04. Therefore, we don't have a 20.04-compatible package.

1. You can try the community-made [Polybar Snap](https://snapcraft.io/polybar-git).
2. You can install Ubuntu 21.04 (the window for *upgrading* from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 to 21.04 has closed).
3. You can try to compile the code yourself.
4. You can [ask for a backport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) of the package to Ubuntu 20.04. (Better yet, you can join the Ubuntu Backporters!)
5. You can be patient: When you upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 in eight months, the package will be in the 22.04 repositories.

Comment: ok thank you. now my files etc. I have things to flash memory again, then install ubuntu, then put ubuntu again, edit the folders, it is very difficult, if I can upgrade like windows, for example, I got it as an update when installing the 2h21 version of windows, so I want to install a program, so I need to upgrade to a new version, but the new version is closed, what should I do, I will install an ubuntu again or I will wait 8 months! i condemn ubuntu

Comment: You might be a bit hasty with the condemnation. Option #1 seems very easy for you to try.

Comment: ı try this ı have an error   https://controlc.com/a825bf7e